# Windows 8 explorer crashing every 30seconds because of twinui.dll

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, crash

my Windows 8.1 PC seems to have a problem. I can't see all icons on the Start Page and the explorer.exe crashes every 30 seconds with the following message in the EventViewer:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
    <Level>2</Level> 
    <Task>100</Task> 
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-05-07T09:45:06.000000000Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>4017142</EventRecordID> 
    <Channel>Application</Channel> 
    <Computer>#########</Computer> 
    <Security /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>explorer.exe</Data> 
    <Data>6.3.9600.17667</Data> 
    <Data>54c6f7c2</Data> 
    <Data>twinui.dll</Data> 
    <Data>6.3.9600.17415</Data> 
    <Data>54503c45</Data> 
    <Data>c0000006</Data> 
    <Data>000000000019d500</Data> 
    <Data>1e1c</Data> 
    <Data>01d088aa7cf26678</Data> 
    <Data>C:\Windows\explorer.exe</Data> 
    <Data>C:\Windows\system32\twinui.dll</Data> 
    <Data>bdc91ae1-f49d-11e4-8307-485ab6f10f4e</Data> 
    <Data /> 
    <Data /> 
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I've tried disabling all Explorer integration from TortoiseSVN, Git, 7-Zip and so on with Autoruns.exe on Keys with \ContextMenuHandlers. But some TortoiseSVN files could not be found...

What else can I do?

Comment: Does this happen in safe mode?

Comment: There is one set of noise on the web that indicated it could have occured from an intel graphics update that happened. (2 people total).   Are you using the intel on-die gpu on this computer?

Comment: @Psycogeek how do Icheck this? It's an EliteBook 8570p

Comment: @Ramhound can't boot into Safe Mode right now because the drive is BitLocker encrypted and I don't have the appropriate key

Comment: Use AutoRuns to determine that, if you are loading the intel video drivers, then dont

Comment: capture a crash dump and share it, I'll try to debug it a bit: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ

Comment: I used shellExView to deactivate all Context Menu handlers and now it stopped. I'll try to reactivate them one by one and see what caused the problem